# Consulta SQL Server Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

Que tal buenas noches,

tengo un problema con una consulta SQL, tengo una tabla de stock, donde los únicos valores que quiero traer son:

-modelo de radios
-estado

Básicamente quiero que los datos se reflejen como si fuera un excel:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAioR.png)

la estructura de la consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
  cod_modelo AS MODELO,
  count(case when  cod_estado='ASG' then 1 else 0 end )  as ASIGNADOS,
  count(case when  cod_estado='DISP' then 1 else 0 end ) AS DISPONIBLE,
  count(case when  cod_estado='F/S' then 1 else 0 end ) AS FUERASERVICIO   
FROM stock_xbodega
GROUP BY cod_modelo
```

me devuelve lo siguiente:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MxTZ.png)

Si bien me devuelve el total de cada modelo de radio, pero no la cantidad de asignadas, disponibles o fuera de servicio

la estructura resumida de la tabla es:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[stock_xbodega](
    [cod_bodega] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [id_stock] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [n_serie] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [cod_estado] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [cod_modelo] [nvarchar](40) NULL
```

Comment: Prueba, `count(select cod_estado from stock_xbodega where cod_estado = 'ASG') AS Asignado`

Comment: No entiendo bien el problema, en sí la consulta no tiene ningún inconveniente, te retorna el conteo de las filas cuando existe un modelo como el que le pasaste. Si solo requieres el estado por qué deseas colocar el COUNT? Eso lo que no comprendo.

Comment: Si! me devuelve el TOTAL que tengo por modelo de radio, necesito que me devuelva el total por el estado de radio, ejemplo:
xtl-1500: 13 asignadas, 20 disponibles, 12 reparacion
apx-1000: 2 asignadas, 5 disponmibles, 1 reparacion

asi como sale en la primera imagen, como un excel

Comment: GROUP BY cod_modelo, cod_estado agrupa por los dos campo a ver q pasa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un problema con estas clausulas:

```
count(case when  cod_estado='ASG' then 1 else 0 end )  as ASIGNADOS,
count(case when  cod_estado='DISP' then 1 else 0 end ) AS DISPONIBLE,
count(case when  cod_estado='F/S' then 1 else 0 end ) AS FUERASERVICIO
```

Básicamente no estas invalidando el `COUNT()`, es decir se esta contando los 1 y lo 0, o sea todas las filas de cada grupo. Para invalidar el `COUNT()` debes usar el `NULL`:

```
count(case when  cod_estado='ASG' then 1 else NULL end )  as ASIGNADOS,
count(case when  cod_estado='DISP' then 1 else NULL end ) AS DISPONIBLE,
count(case when  cod_estado='F/S' then 1 else NULL end ) AS FUERASERVICIO
```

O bien usar directamente el `SUM()`:

```
sum(case when  cod_estado='ASG' then 1 else 0 end )  as ASIGNADOS,
sum(case when  cod_estado='DISP' then 1 else 0 end ) AS DISPONIBLE,
sum(case when  cod_estado='F/S' then 1 else 0 end ) AS FUERASERVICIO
```

Comment: Excelente Patricio gracias! Tienes razón, debía usar Null para invalidarlo, con el 0 recorría todad las filas muchas gracias